# Is there a way that my application in azure can connect directly to Oracle Database on premise

Tags: oracle, azure, migrate

I intend to migrate my application into azure but the oracle database which the application connects to is still on premise.
Is there a way that my application on azure can connect directly to Oracle Database on premise

Comment: That will depend entirely on if/how your Azure network is connected to your on-premise network. It is *not* automatic. Talk to whomever is in charge of your Azure networking services to find out; this isn't something that this forum can answer.

Comment: Ale be aware that Oracles protocol might be sensitive to network latencies.